# Communication between two different pages with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I'm trying to make it so when the user presses a button on page A.html and it will dynamically change an image on page B.html using socket.io (hosted on the same webserver). Is it possible to add a deliberate delay, like with setTimeout()?

Comment: You can always do a setTimeout just before emitting or a setTimeout just after reading so as to delay the change in image on B.html. As of socket.io, I don't think there is a way to add a delay in sending the data.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add a deliberate delay, like with setTimeout()?

Yes, a delay can be added either in the client or the server.  For example, in the page A client:

```
// after one second delay, send the message to the server
setTimeout(function() {
    socket.emit("changeImage", "pageB");
}, 1000);
```

Or, on the server:

```
socket.on("changeImage", function(data) {
    if (data === "pageB") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            socket.emit("changeImageB", "pageB");
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Or even in the pageB client:

```
// listen for message to change the image
socket.on("changeImageB", function(data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // change image in the DOM here
    }, 1000);

});
```